# How can i change j/M/y date format to timestamp?

Tags: php, excel, date, phpexcel, date-format

I tried convert to timestamp but not working, My code is below

```
$date = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A' . $x)->getFormattedValue();//output value is 9/Feb/16

echo strtotime($date);//return value is empty
```

It's return empty value. I want to compare Excel sheet date and PHP returned date.
Excel sheet returned date is like this `->` **9/Feb/16**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value in the cell is an MS Excel serialized timestamp, then you can get the "raw" value from the cell

```
$date = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell('A' . $x)->getValue();
```

which should return a number like 42409 for 2nd February 2016

Then use the built-in date/time conversion functions to convert that either to a unix timestamp, or to a PHP DateTime object

```
$date = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($date); // returns a unix timestamp
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $date);
```

or

```
$date = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($date); // returns a DateTime object
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to change slashes to minus symbol so `strtotime` will recognize you $date as date

```
$date = str_replace('/','-',$date);
echo strtotime($date); //output 1454976000
```

[`live sample`](http://codepad.org/2RhPBLCv)

Answer (score 1):

```
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('j/M/y', '9/Feb/16');
echo $d->getTimestamp();
```